# Making dynamic code in Cucumber with the Page Object Model

Tags: selenium, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Is there a way perform actions dynamically using Cucumber?

Example:

Feature File:

```
Scenario: Click all the boxes
    Given On the checkbox page
    When Click checkboxA
    And Click checkboxB
```

Step Definition:

```
@When("Click checkboxA")
public void clickCheckBoxA()
{
   pageObject.checkBoxA.click();
}

@And("Click checkboxB")
public void clickCheckBoxB()
{
   pageObject.checkBoxB.click();
}
```

In this scenario, there are two very similar step definitions.  The reason why there are two different definitions is because each WebElement is defined in the pageObject Class.  Is there a way to dynamically pass which checkbox we want to click, rather than having two separate methods performing the same action?

The only way I can think to do this is by passing a selector as a parameter in the feature step and instantiating the webElement within the step definition method.  But that seems like bad practice to me.

Answer (score 2):

`Click` is your step. It should not be unique for each item you may want to click. You should match what you want to click with a regular expression. The following combines your two steps into one.

```
@When("^Click (.*)$")
public void clickElement(String elementToClick) {
  switch (elementToClick) {
  case "checkBoxA":
    pageObject.checkBoxA.click();
  case "checkBoxB":
    pageObject.checkBoxB.click();
  }
}
```

I'd suggest using a smarter regex match (this one is lazy and sloppy) and you could also create a new variable for the element to be clicked, assign its value to your existing element in each `case` and have a single call to `click()` after the `switch` statement.

Regarding your question of doing this "dynamically," you cannot do so in Java (I think you were thinking of having a single line in the example I gave above of `pageObject.elementToClick.click();`?) because it's a compiled programming language; your code can't be altered at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to use @mike's solution, but in some cases I tend to create a locator as string in POM so that it reduces lines of code in the step definition.

Feature File:

```
Scenario: Click all the boxes
  Given On the checkbox page
  When Click checkbox A
  And Click checkbox B
```

POM:

```
private String checkBox = "//input[text()='checkBox%s']";
```

Step Definition:

```
@When("Click checkbox (.*)")
public void handleCheckBox(String checkBoxName) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(checkBox, checkBoxName))).click();
}
```

Comment: I think it all depends on how elements are being found. If the original posted is already using Xpath, your solution is much better as it doesn't need new code for each new element. It would be even better if this elements had IDs, but we're getting away from the question. My solution is purposely verbose because it sounded like they wanted to use the elements they had already located. Your solution is very good and the overall model I'd probably follow if doing this from scratch.

Comment: @Mike Collins, This approach works with any locator, which we can parameterise some part of that.